# How to add text box at the end in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I need to add at the end of the Google Form a piece of text saying that respondents can withdraw their consent at any one time. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

To show the endnote *after* the user clicks **Submit**:

1. Click the gear icon ⚙︎  in the top right-hand corner.
2. Click **Presentation**.
3. Enter your endnote in the **Confirmation message** box.

To show the endnote *before* the user clicks **Submit**:

1. Select the last question.
2. Click the `Tt` icon in the toolbar in the right to insert a text box.
3. If you want the text box to start with a header, enter it in the **Title** box.
4. Enter your endnote in the **Description** box.